# Cambiar css de botón visitado en menú de navegación cargado desde archivo externo con php

Tags: php, javascript, menú

Estoy intentando cambiar el css a uno de los botones en un menú de navegación para indicar en qué página se encuentra el usuario.

Tengo un header con un menú de navegación cargado desde un fichero externo con include de php

```
<?php include "files/header_lp.html" ?>
```

En el archivo javascript, estoy intentado crear una clase para dar formato al link activo del menú.

```
$(".nav li").on("click", hover_menu);

function hover_menu(){
    $(".nav li").removeClass("activo");
    $(this).addClass("activo");
}
```

El problema que encuentro es que posiblemente el archivo JS se carga antes de que php incluya el archivo. ¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?

Por otra parte, el link al hacer click abre una nueva página, por lo que vuelve a cargar la nueva página eliminando la clase creada con JS.

Estoy pensando cargar el menú en cada página para darle formato al link cada vez que lo cargue, o incluso he pensado en recuperar el titulo o el url de la página para utilizarlo en un condicional y cambiar el botón, pero no funcionará cuando use anclas y el título de la página podría cambiar, igual lo considero unas soluciones muy rebuscadas preferiría no evitar el problema sino solucionarlo.

Comment: Puedes poner ese mismo script en la página PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Se utiliza $(window).load(function(){}) para esperar a que todos los elementos de la página estén listos.

```
$(window).load(function() {  
  $(".nav li").on("click", hover_menu);  
});  

function hover_menu(){  
  $(".nav li").removeClass("activo");  
  $(this).addClass("activo");  
}
```

En este caso también se puede utilizar $(document).ready(function(){}) porque sólo necesitas esperar al DOM.

Comment: Hola @Alejandro. Creo que está respuesta podría beneficiarse si incluyeras una breve descripción del evento que agregaste y por qué

Comment: Gracias quizás no lo se explicar bien! Tengo un  menú de navegación llamado por archivo externo con php. Lo que quiero es cambiarle de color al boton de navegación para que indique en qué página me me encuentro. Para ello intenté crear una clase con JQuery cada vez que alguien hace click en el botón. El problema es que no me funciona y supongo que será porque cargo el menu desde php.

Comment: Si tienes tu código js encapsulado en el Document Ready no creo que sea un problema de PHP. La función del Document Ready es la de no ejecutar tu código js hasta que todos los elementos del DOM estén cargados, indiferentemente de si vienen de un HTML estático, PHP, un require de PHP, etc.

$(document).ready(function() {
    aquí tu código
});

Puedes compartir tu clase para ver si hay algún error.